# Selenium wait till page is fully load using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

Given a site, AJAX components on the page and I need to wait till the whole page is fully loaded.

Here is my wait method using JavascriptExecutor checking document.readyState:

```
public void waitForLoading2() {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);
        if(!driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='wait'][contains(@style, 'display: block')]")).isEmpty()) {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='wait'][contains(@style, 'display: none')]")));
        }

            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
                    ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("complete");
                        }
                    };
            wait.until(expectation);

    }
```

Sometimes it's failing with the following Error msg:

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: JavaScript error (WARNING:
>   The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

What did I miss here? My assumption is that document.readyState is common and always can be checked.

Thanks

Comment: Achieving `document.readyState` is internal to Selenium. What is your exact usecase? What are you trying to validate?

Comment: Sometimes the page is loading without any interaction and I just want to wait till the page is fully loaded. Waiting for particular element is not an option here, so readyState would be the best option except this javascript error :)

Comment: To quote the docs, _because of cross domain policies browsers enforce your script execution may fail unexpectedly and without adequate error messaging. This is particularly pertinent when creating your own XHR request or when trying to access another frame. Most times when troubleshooting failure it's best to view the browser's console after executing the WebDriver request._

Answer (score 1):

There are more [complex options](http://hrabosch.com/2016/05/12/35/), like this one

```
public static void waitForAjax(WebDriver driver, String action) {
       driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
               "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                       "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                       "xhr.open('POST', '/" + action + "', true);" +
                       "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
                       "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
                       "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
                       "  }" +
                       "};" +
                       "xhr.send();");
}
```

in order

> to wait till the whole page is fully loaded

But the following did the trick for me - I check if there are ongoing AJAX calls and wait till those are done:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driverjs;
js.executeScript("return((window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0))").equals("true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking `document.readyState` will not help you with AJAX calls. Your best bet is to find an element in the area being loaded by AJAX and wait until it is visible. Then you'll know that the page is loaded. If there are multiple/separate areas loaded by AJAX calls, then you will want to pick an element from each area.

Comment: Most of the time, webtable elements appears on the page, very hard to locate them and not too easy to work with. Thats' why I try to solve somehow else. Most of the time, document.readyState is working fine, but sometimes l get Javascript error.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery to send AJAX request, you can get the value of `jQuery.active`. it's equivalent to all AJAX requests complete when `jQuery.active=0`.

Use `executeScript("return jQuery.active==0")`. For detail please read this [artical](https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/)